# Pulumi,serviceAccountKey.privateKeyData call back param is null problem

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, pulumi

Here is my code in index.ts

```
    import {Key, ServiceAccount} from "@pulumi/google-native/iam/v1";

    const serviceAccountKey = new Key('service-account-key-' + new Date().toISOString(), {
      serviceAccountId: serviceAccount.email
    });

    export const serviceAccountKeyStr = serviceAccountKey.privateKeyData.apply(
    async privateKeyData => {
      console.log("========privateKeyData=========",privateKeyData);
    return privateKeyData;
    }
```

but the output is

> ========privateKeyData========= undefined

---

what's wrong with my code ?

I want to update my google cloud IAM service Account key with Pulumi. but serviceAccountKey.privateKeyData is null.
however others params is not null(eg:serviceAccountKey.name & serviceAccountKey.serviceAccountId ...)

so,I really want to know why it is

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fix this by my colleague.
There are some problems in the package above `@pulumi/google-native/iam/v1` ,so just use another package `@pulumi/gcp`.
The Example is :https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/serviceaccount/key/